# Trigger mainframe job from AirFlow

Tags: airflow, scheduler, mainframe

May I know if AirFlow support Mainframe jobs ? Can we schedule Mainframe jobs using AirFlow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Airflow website - I could not see any mention of mainframes so the answer would appear to be 'No'. But you could always ask Airflow although there does not appear to be a 'Contact us' link.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why not use a native scheduler?

Comment: `Airflow` imposes no restrictions on kind of jobs that it can schedule. Anything that can be invoked via a Python script can be triggered by `Airflow`

Answer (score 2):

I do not know airflow specifically, but we have used Ansible, Jenkins, and IBM Urban Code Deploy for orchestration that includes distributed and mainframe process parts.

You can SSH into z/OS and use Bash, Python, cURL, Node.js, or Groovy.  You could submit JCL via REST APIs. There is a command line processor for Db2 to execute SQL and stored procedures via bash terminal. There is the new Zowe CLI that brings a modern command line interface to z/OS.

I would ask the question - what is the nature of what you want to be scheduled?  What language is it written in, or what language do you want it written in?  If something exists today, what is the process and how is it scheduled today?

While I haven't used airflow, you can use modern interfaces to do things on z/OS, and frequently that is what is actually needed to integrate with orchestration tools.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Patrick Bossman's good summary, Apache Airflow definitely supports SSH connections to run commands and/or transfer files:

https://airflow.apache.org/howto/connection/ssh.html

z/OS includes OpenSSH as a standard, IBM supported feature in the base operating system at no additional charge, although it's possible it's not running in your particular z/OS installation. Dovetailed Technologies has published a helpful "Quick Install Guide" that explains how to configure and start OpenSSH on z/OS if it isn't configured already:

http://dovetail.com/docs/pt-quick-inst/pt-quick-inst-doc.pdf

Their reference points to IBM's official z/OS documentation if you need more information.

You may decide to have other connections to z/OS from Apache Airflow, but SSH is certainly an available option.

FYI, it appears possible to run Apache Airflow directly on z/OS 2.4 itself. I haven't personally tried it, but it looks good to go. The recipe to do that would be as follows:

1. Configure and fire up the [z/OS Container Extensions ("zCX")](https://www.ibm.com/support/z-content-solutions/container-extensions/), a standard, included, IBM supported, no additional charge feature in z/OS 2.4 that's compatible with IBM z14 and higher model IBM Z machines.
2. Install and run a Python container (Docker/OCI format) on zCX, for example a [Python container from DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python). You'll need a Python container image that includes "s390x" architecture support, either on its own or in a multi-architecture container. (No problem with DockerHub's image.)
3. Use pip to install Apache Airflow within your Python container, per normal.
4. Configure your SSH (and perhaps other) connection(s) from Airflow to the rest of z/OS, as described above.

You can also run Apache Airflow on Linux on Z/LinuxONE, either on the same IBM Z machine where z/OS runs or on a different machine. You can test Apache Airflow using the free (for up to 120 days) [IBM LinuxONE Community Cloud](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxone/), and you could even create your own custom Docker/OCI container on the LinuxONE Community Cloud for deployment to zCX.

It might even be possible to run Airflow on Python for z/OS, without zCX, although if so there'd be some more work involved. Python for z/OS is available from Rocket Software here:

https://www.rocketsoftware.com/product-categories/mainframe/python-for-zos